# android:popup window like facebook?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a popup window like facebook notification. In which when i click it should popup and come  normal position when click again.My Screen shot shows below

[image]
Regards Augustine

Please Help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use dialog with setContetnView()

```
Dialog _dialog = new Dialog(this);
_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourxml);
_dialog.show();
```

with for this and by using a boolean flag you can get this feature..